# when I use replace("\\","x") ,it dosenot work

Tags: javascript, replace

When I use replace() to change value,after replace,value of nt is "sssss",not "sssxss";who can tell me how to change nt to "sssxss";

```
var t = "sss\ss";
var nt = t.replace("\\","x");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash in the variable declaration as well...

```
var t = "sss\\ss";
var nt = t.replace("\\","x");
```

Incidentally, if it's relevant, `replace()` will only replace the first occurrence.  If you want to replace all occurrences then use a regular expression or split and join the string.

Comment: How can this be right, you have changed the input i.e. the `t` variable to make this work. Assuming the questioner only has one `\\` in the data he is changing this is NOT an answer to the question!!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly the value he assigns to `t` ends up not having a backslash in it, as `\s` is escaped and becomes `s`.  This answer is an explanation of what he had done wrong.  It's impossible to do anything else since the backslash doesn't exist in his example.

Comment: I see your point, I'll put this down to a badly worded question